# Bind Db context lifecycle to TransactionScope

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I am new to Entity framework core but have used Nhibernate and Java Hibernate for years and I'd like to bind `DbContext` to transaction scope.

So method calls from service layer to business layers for a given use case are surrounded by a transaction (unit of work) :

```cs
using(var txScope = new TransactionScope(/*TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled, isolation level, etc...*/)) 
{

    // calls to business layer methods
    txScope.Complete();
}
```

To bind a `DbContext` to the current transaction I wrote this helper class, inspired by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

```cs
class DbContextHolder<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, T> activeDbContexts = new();

    private readonly Func<T> creator;

    public DbContextHolder(Func<T> creator) => this.creator = creator;

    public T GetDbContext()
    {
        System.Transactions.Transaction tx = System.Transactions.Transaction.Current ?? throw new Exception("cannot manage a db context outside a transaction");

        string txId = tx.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier;
        if (activeDbContexts.TryGetValue(txId, out var dbContext))
        {
            return dbContext;
        }
        else
        {
            T ctx = creator();
            ctx.Database.OpenConnection(); // borrow connection from pool
            ctx.Database.EnlistTransaction(tx);

            tx.TransactionCompleted += (x, y) =>
            {
                ctx.Dispose(); // releases connection
                activeDbContexts.Remove(txId);
            };
            return ctx;
        }
    }
}
```

All access to the DB within a given transaction use the same connection, borrowed from the pool.

Do you see any pitfalls ?

This class can be declared in a service collection

```cs
.AddSingleton(new DbContextHolder<MyContext>(() => new MyContext(options)))
```

and the singleton can be injected into business layer classes. In business layer methods:

```cs
MyContext ctx = dbContextHolder/*injected*/.GetContext();
```

With a inheritance based proxy on `MyContext` that forwards calls to `dbBontext.GetContext()`, the business layer could receive a `MyContext` object (the proxy).

Comment: *Do you see any pitfalls?* -- Starting a transaction (and opening a db connection) only when initiating a context is a waste of resources. What if you only want to read some data? The more important question is, why do you want this at all? Code using EF should rely on EF's own transaction handling, i.e. it should be exceptional that you need more than one `SaveChanges` call in one unit of work.

Comment: The point is to share the same DbContext across several methods, all involved in the same transaction. Should each method create and dispose a DbContext (which involes borrow and release a connection) ? For reads it is less needed, I agree.

Comment: You don't need a TransactionScope for an ambient context, but you need a mechanism that ensures that only the last `SaveChanges` call is actually effective.. This problem was solved before. Look for *DbContextScope*.

Answer (score 0):

Binding a DbContext to a transaction scope explicitly is generally only required when you want a transaction scope to wrap both access to a DbContext *and* other transaction-bound services (other DbContexts, or processes like file management etc. that can support roll-back) together within a transaction. A DbContext instance itself can be shared across methods that interact with the DbContext where-by the changes are all persisted or rolled back based on whether `SaveChanges()` is called and is successful.

I'd also be wary of seeing a class like your DbContextHelper in code solely because DbContexts should be short-lived and I'm wary of any code that wants to pool instances of the same DbContext type.

In ASP.Net MVC for instance when you set up your dependency injection, EF can be configured so that the IoC container can instantiate your DbContext instance and scope it to the web request. In this way every dependency service etc. that takes an injected DbContext is getting the exact same instance so you get something like this:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context = null;
     
    public SomeController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    public ActionResult SomeAction(/*parameters*/)
    {
         SomeService.Method(/*params*/);
         SomeOtherService.Method(/*params*/);
         _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Where like the controller, the SomeService and SomeOtherService accept an injected AppDbContext. The IoC container can be configured to use a factory method/class or such to set up the DbContext instance, and when scoped to the request, everything gets the same AppDbContext instance.

The downside I find with this approach is that you don't really have any fine control over the scope of operations. The Context is scoped to the request so while it's convenient to not have to worry about it for the bulk of simple scenarios, you cannot easily reuse those services and such within a smaller scope, say for example you need something like a retry, or want to persist some alternative audit log entity in the event of an error. The single `DbContext` instance that the services all reference can be "poisoned" with the entities that it wasn't able to save correctly and we cannot easily dump and recreate it. We also have a bit of an issue that it isn't intuitive when and where a `SaveChanges()` call against the `DbContext` should be allowed/expected. As a general rule, within a scope of operations there should only be one `SaveChanges()` call. It could be easy to end up seeing `SaveChanges()` appearing within some, or all of the services, and depending on what service methods you happen to call, you could end up with several `SaveChanges()` calls, unexpected exceptions, or just inconsistent behaviour. This often leads to a desire to start wrapping the `DbContext` with a `TransactionScope`.

The first issue around scoping can be addressed by being more explicit with the scoping of the `DbContext`. Rather having the IoC container inject a DbContext, we can inject something like a `DbContext` Factory class that handles our context setup:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(/*parameters*/)
{
    using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
    {
         try
         {
             SomeService.Method(/*params*/, context);
             SomeOtherService.Method(/*params*/, context);
             context.SaveChanges();
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             AuditService.LogException("SomeAction could not be completed due to an exception.", ex); 
             throw;
             // Where AuditService scopes its own context or...
             /*
             using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
             {
                 var audit = AuditService.LogException("SomeAction could not be completed due to an exception.", ex, context);
                 SomeOtherService.SomeExceptionMethod(/*params*/, context);
                 context.SaveChanges();
             } 
             */
         }
    }
}
```

However, with this pattern while it is more intuitive that a `SaveChanges()` call should occur at the end of the DbContext's scope (handling any exceptions) there isn't anything stopping inner service calls from calling `SaveChanges()`. It's also a bit "ugly" because each service method needs to accept the DbContext as a parameter because it is the caller that is managing the DbContext scope.

This is where Unit of Work patterns come in. These are effectively scope wrappers for a DbContext, and can also manage an overarching transaction scope so that if subordinates happen to call `SaveChanges()` this still conforms to the expectation that the outer scope ultimately decides if the unit of work is committed or not and how failures might be handled. The UoW wrapper that I use is the DbContextScope from Medi El Gueddari. (https://github.com/mehdime/DbContextScope) There are forks available for EF Core as well. The dependencies are split into two parts, effectively a Factory and a Context Scope Locator. Your top-level services/controllers would inject a factory to set up the lifetime of a DbContextScope (Unit of Work) while subordinate services would have the AmbientDbContextScopeLocator injected to locate any DbContextScope they are called within to get access to a DbContext.

Using this pattern the method looks a bit more like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(/*parameters*/)
{
    using (var contextScope = DbContextScopeFactory.Create())
    {
         try
         {
             SomeService.Method(/*params*/);
             SomeOtherService.Method(/*params*/);
             contextScope.SaveChanges();
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             AuditService.LogException("SomeAction could not be completed due to an exception.", ex); 
             throw;
             // Where AuditService scopes its own context or...
             /*
             using (var contextScope = DbContextScopeFactory.Create())
             {
                 var audit = AuditService.LogException("SomeAction could not be completed due to an exception.", ex, context);
                 SomeOtherService.SomeExceptionMethod(/*params*/);
                 contextScope.SaveChanges();
             }
             */
         }
    }
}
```

This looks similar to just scoping a DbContext, but the key difference here is we don't need to pass a reference to the DbContext, or the DbContextScope into each and every service method call as a parameter. The services will locate the Context Scope themselves.

The supporting services take an `IAmbientDbContextLocator` dependency and contain the following to get their DbContext:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IAmbientDbContextLocator _dbContextLocator = null;
     
    private AppDbContext Context => _dbContextLocator.Get<AppDbContext>() ?? throw new ApplicationException("The DbContext Scope was not initialize or could not resolve the AppDbContext.");

    public SomeService(IAmbientDbContextLocator dbContextLocator)
    {
        _dbContextLocator = dbContextLocator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContextLocator");
    }
}
```

This can work with a single application DbContext, or bounded DbContexts. (where you use several area-specific DbContexts rather than one large one) You only need one DbContextScope to create/retrieve any number of DbContext instances.

All of the methods within the service can now access the `DbContext` via the private Context property. In the rare event that they actually need to call `SaveChanges` on the DbContext such as to get the PK for a newly created entity to pass along to an external service or such, that is perfectly fine as well. The records are not "final" until the `DbContextScope.SaveChanges()` method is successfully called.

The DbContextScope implementation also supports ReadOnly scopes which are a bit faster and help set the expectation that the call chain does not expect/support saving data. The implementation even handles cases where you might want a service to manage its own DbContextScope where it might be called while already within a Scope.    (such as with something like a LoggingService where you want to write log entries without worrying about other "poisoned" entities) By default the `Create()` methods will throw if they are called within an existing scope since that would generally be a bug but you can allow it by using:  `DbContextScopeFactory.Create(DbContextScopeOption.ForceCreateNew)`

I definitely recommend having a look at this UoW implementation, or others out there as they should achieve what you are likely aiming for.